# How to prevent hot corners when playing games on full screen?

Tags: 14.04, unity, games

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 with Unity and I love the hot corners feature, but it still works when I'm playing games on full screen (like Dota 2). So, during the game, if I pass the mouse around some corners, it will show all workspaces, all windows etc. Is it a bug? How do I prevent hotcorners when playing games on full screen?